# Making intent to send SMS, not only open sms creation

Tags: android, button, sms, android-intent, widget

I have an app with widget. Three buttons on widget should sent predefined SMS messages to predefined numbers ... this is my code:

```
package cro.perger.bonbon;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;



        public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                        int[] appWidgetIds) {

                            String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");

                            for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

                                Intent callIntent1  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                                         Uri.parse("tel:*100" + encodedHash));
                                Intent callIntent2  = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
                                         Uri.parse("tel:*200*1" + encodedHash));

                                Intent sendIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                sendIntent1.putExtra("sms_body", "Poruka 1");
                                sendIntent1.putExtra("address", "5556");
                                sendIntent1.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

                                Intent sendIntent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                sendIntent2.putExtra("sms_body", "Poruka 2");
                                sendIntent2.putExtra("address", "5556");
                                sendIntent2.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

                                Intent sendIntent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                sendIntent3.putExtra("sms_body", "Poruka 3");
                                sendIntent3.putExtra("address", "5556");
                                sendIntent3.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

                                Intent openintent = new Intent(context, bonbon.class);

                                PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent1, 0);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent2, 0);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sendIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sendIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent5 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sendIntent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent6 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openintent, 0);

                                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent1);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent2);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button3, pendingIntent3);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button4, pendingIntent4);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button5, pendingIntent5);
                                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button6, pendingIntent6);

                                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

                            }

                }

        }
```

Problem is that button3, button4 and button5 (when I click on them) don't send sms, but only open new sms screen, and I need to click on send SMS. What do I need to change, that SMS automaticly sends to recipient ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ripped some of my old code from an app, this should work for sending SMS messages:

```
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;

 send_text_message (Number, "This is a message"); 

private void send_text_message (String phoneNumber, String message) 
{
 if (phoneNumber.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0)
 {
  Log.i (TAG, "MyPhoneStateListener: onCallStateChanged(); test text sent to " + phoneNumber);    
  sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);      
 }
 else
 {
  Log.i (TAG, "MyPhoneStateListener: onCallStateChanged(); test text was NOT sent to " + phoneNumber);                   
 }
}   

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{                     
 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
 sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a SMS message, you should check out the `SmsManager` and `sendTextMessage()` in the official documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

Comment: Can you help me, to put this into my code, i don't get this very clear :(

Comment: Well, basically you should just use this:
`SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);`

Comment: Sorry, not too sure how your code works. My guess would be that you need to set a onClickListener for each of the buttons in the RemoteViews variable, and then use my code in the listener, but again, I'm not sure how your app works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SmsManager and the method sendTextMessage()

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EnvoieSms extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //On récupère le bouton créer en XML grâce à son id
    Button btnEnvoie = (Button)findViewById(R.id.envoyer);
    //On récupère les deux EditText correspondant aux champs pour entrer le numéro et le message
    final EditText numero =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.numero);
    final EditText message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
    //On affecte un écouteur d'évènement au bouton
    btnEnvoie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //On récupère ce qui a été entré dans les EditText
            String num = numero.getText().toString();
            String msg = message.getText().toString();
            //Si le numéro est supérieur à 4 charactère et que le message n'est pas vide on lance la procédure d'envoi
            if(num.length()>= 4 && msg.length() > 0){
                //Grâce à l'objet de gestion de SMS (SmsManager) que l'on récupère grâce à la méthode static getDefault()
                //On envoit le SMS à l'aide de la méthode sendTextMessage
                SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(num, null, msg, null, null);
                //On efface les deux EditText
                numero.setText("");
                message.setText("");
            }else{
                //On affiche un petit message d'erreur dans un Toast
                Toast.makeText(EnvoieSms.this, "Enter le numero et/ou le message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this, but can't get it to work, because my code is in widget file, so always has some errors with this :(